# DEP0500 error being raise for WinRT Metro app when compiling

Tags: wpf, deployment, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

When I compile I often get the following error:

Error   28
Error : DEP0500 : The folder "C:\Code\Cloud\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. 
Access to the path 'C:\Code\Cloud\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\AppX\ControlsProject.Controls\Themes' is denied.

If I close down Visual Studio (2012 RC) I can delete the folder and recompile so I'm assuming VS is locking the file for some reason.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Has anyone found a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/41f06523-5b36-4b22-86b3-32a4b366e732) is what you're probably looking for. Seems like you have two options - either re-create the solution file or use Process Explorer to close existing handles to the locked path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that worked for me - reset your VS settings.

http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/dep0500-and-dep1000-errors-when-deploying-windows-store-apps-from-vs/

Answer (score 0):

I'm handling this problem using LockHunter.

1. Download LockHunter at http://lockhunter.com/download.htm.
2. Create a shortcut to the AppX folder on your desktop.
3. Whenever AppX is locked in Visual Studio open the shortcut to AppX.
4. Right-click AppX and select "What is locking this folder". This will open LockHunter.
5. In LockHunter click "Unlock it!".

After unlocking AppX go back to Visual Studio and compile/run the project.